# Deploying Code to Airflow without a Full Restart

Tags: airflow

I have a celery apache-airflow setup with one worker node on an EC2 instance. For code deployment, the user triggers deployment, copying the code package to s3; some infra related script copies the code package from s3 onto the instance; the instance triggers a restart of ALL the airflow-related services.

I want to make it so that whenever I need to modify the code, ideally any jobs that are currently running should still continue to run, without using a cluster setup.

I'm thinking that maybe finding a way to restart the web server and scheduler without restarting the worker could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with `Airflow` in **`LocalExecutor`**, merely changing the

- DAG-definition file (possible modifying structure of DAG)
- Code of Operators
- Inputs of DAG / Tasks ([like `Variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081784/3679900), `Connection`s)

does NOT require restarting Airflow services (`webserver` and `scheduler`)

---

- Its only when you change the scheduling parameters of your DAG, namely `start_date` and `schedule_interval`, that [renaming of `dag_id` is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028555/3679900)
- I've read suggestions that if I don't want to rename my DAG, restarting `Airflow` services would also do the trick. But I've found that this claim is inconsistent (does not work always)

---

*do note that above facts are with reference to `LocalExecutor` and they may not hold true for `CeleryExecutor`*

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

However as for `Airflow` `scheduler` (and virtually any long running process in general), [it is recommended](https://medium.com/handy-tech/airflow-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls-9ba53fba14eb) that it must be restarted from time to time.

> **The scheduler should be restarted frequently**
>
> In our experience, a long
>   running scheduler process, at least with the CeleryExecutor, ends up
>   not scheduling some tasks. We still don’t know the exact cause,
>   unfortunately. Fortunately, airflow has a built-in workaround in the
>   form of the — num_runs flag. It specifies a number of iterations for
>   the scheduler to run of its loop before it quits. We’re running it
>   with 10 iterations, Airbnb runs it with 5. Note that this will cause
>   problems when using the LocalExecutor.

*the above article is from 2015, not sure if things have changed since*