# Airflow Access Variable From Previous Python Operator

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Airflow and I'm currently building a DAG that will execute a PythonOperator, a BashOperator, and then another PythonOperator structured like this:

```
def authenticate_user(**kwargs):
    ...
    list_prev = [...]

AUTHENTICATE_USER = PythonOperator(
        task_id='AUTHENTICATE_USER',
        python_callable=authenticate_user,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag)

CHANGE_ROLE = BashOperator(
        task_id='CHANGE_ROLE',
        bash_command='...',
        dag=dag)

def calculations(**kwargs):
    list_prev
    ...

CALCULATIONS = PythonOperator(
    task_id='CALCULATIONS',
    python_callable=calculations,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

My issue is, I create a list of variables in the first PythonOperator (AUTHENTICATE_USER) that I would like to use later in my second PythonOperator (CALCULATIONS) after executing the BashOperator (CHANGE_ROLE). Is there a way for me to carry over that created list into other PythonOperators in my current DAG?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 3 possible ways (to avoid confusion with the [Airflow's concept of `Variable`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#variables), I'll call the data that you want to share between tasks as `value`s)

1. [**Airflow `XCOM`s**](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms): [Push](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L959) your values from `AUTHENTICATE_USER` task and [pull](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L973) them in your `CALCULATIONS` task. You can either publish and access each value separately or wrap them all into a Python dict or list (better as it reduces db reads and writes)
2. **External system**: Persist your values from 1st task into some external system such as database, files or S3-objects and access them from downstream tasks when needed
3. [**Airflow `Variable`s**](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#variables): This is a specific case of point (2) above (as Variables are stored in Airflow's backend meta-db). You can **programmatically create, modify or delete Variables** by exploiting the underlying `SQLAlchemy` model. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471221/3679900) for hints.